# Read a file name list and perform code on each file in that list.

Tags: python, list, input, output

I seem to be encountering a problem every time I run this program. I am new to programming and with some help me and my partner have developed this code. Essentially there is a text tile called "Files" which contains the names of 80,000+ files to be analysed. A brief outline - The code needs to run over all the data files and return a set of file names in the output file if  R_1 or R_2 has a value in the range of 0.9 to 1.1.

I have made an attempt at trying to read the names of the file but it does not seem to work. Every time it simply says indent error expected indent, then once I have added an indent, it says unexpected indent in that same location. I have made a replica directory on sky drive of the data files and code, and included the 3 data files I am using to develop this code. The skydrive thing did not let me add the suitable data text files which was essentially a blank file.

https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=E5A0B5D5F1A45A4D!231&authkey=!AJQqmATbrTr2Rko&ithint=folder%2c.txt

I know this probably isn't the most efficient code for this but any help with the file input and output will be greatly appreciated. Also in the file name file, i have simply put the data file names because they are in the same directory, so i assume the code will run in this directory and therefore the full file paths are not needed... is that a valid assumption or will i need to include the full path to each file?

Thank you!

Comment: Please read http://sscce.org/ and include a minimal example in your question.

Comment: Wild guess for your indentation problems: indentation has to be consistent. In the same block you cannot use tabs on one line and spaces on the following line, even if in your text editor it seems that the two lines are correctly aligned. I had a quick glance to your Python source code, and this is the only thing that came to my mind, since I didn't see any possibly blatant indentation errors of any kind.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your editor settings to:

1. Use 4 spaces instead of each tab
2. Strip training spaces off each line

As the line after your for has more spaces/tabs than the next line.